# Applying Specular Highlights Separately? (Eevee Nodes)

Tags: node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes, toon-shading

For a bit of context for what I'm stuck on: I'm working on an original anime/toon shader for skin. It takes the base texture colour and applies a colorramp-ed shadow from a principled bsdf shader with multiply, so I get full control of shadow colour. This is working great so far. (Ignore the unfinished hair on my zombie nurse girl. lol)

[image: lighting]

With light vs no light, it's pretty subtle.

[image: node setup]

Node setup.

The issue is I'm struggling to do a similar thing for specular. I want to add some small specular highlights in their own setup so I can control colour and not have any subtle lighting affect my toon shaded character.

I've made a roughness map with targeted on a few areas (lips, nose, cheek, etc....) This would work great on a regular BSDF setup, but I run into a few issues.

[image: image with issues circled]

When applied with the nodes as above, the shader bleaches out parts of the model (The eyeliner must be kept dark.) There should be no specular on the eyeliner so I believe this is being caused by the lighting on the shader reacting to the lighting. I want to remove this.

Is there a way to apply ONLY the specular highlights from this shader? Or a better shader to use, which doesn't react to lighting in any other way? With the shadow setup, it was simple as I only allowed it to darken the model with multiply.

(Additionally I'd also like to add a colorramp to toon-ify the specular dots but hopefully this will fit in later.)

TLDR: Eevee node setup to apply JUST specular light dots over another shader?